# toBeInTheDocument recognized by TypeScript but not WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, vitest, nx-monorepo

Our TypeScript config for our vitest specs appears to be correct, because there's no red lines anywhere (we use jest forms like `toEqual` even though I think vitest "prefers" chai's `to.equal` and it seems to be fine with that).

However, WebStorm still has issues with RTL's `toBeInTheDocument`. Adding `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'` to the top of my file satisfies TypeScript on that one but it's still showing up white with a squiggle:

[image]

It doesn't have any *real* effect, it's just annoying for me to see this as my eyes move about the code. What can I do about this?

FYI our `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "vitest/importMeta", "vite/client", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["./*.d.ts", "./src/**/*.spec.ts", "./src/**/*.spec.tsx"]
}
```

You can see it inherits from the NX library's `tsconfig.json` which inherits from the NX monorepo's `tsconfig.base.json`. I'm pretty positive that most of that doesn't matter but I will paste in these rules from the `base`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      // lots of paths to NX libraries
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
```

Comment: Since you mention tsconfig files with different names, could it be related to this [file order issue Elena Pogorelova describes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008176680-Webstorm-not-resolving-module-imports-using-typescript-paths?page=1#community_comment_360001660420) where WebStorm infers the wrong tsconfig file?

Comment: Thanks but that looks like a different problem, which I've had in the past myself especially when switching branches. There are no actual TS errors, just Webstorm "issues" (like when it suggests inlining a return statement, which is not a TS issue)